# Revalidate the form Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony

In one line, how to valid a form again manually ?

I need to modify the object of my form after handleRequest() if the form was submitted.

But if I check if the form isValid() I get always false.

I think the validity is check in handleRequest() but I need to check again after modify the object form.

```
public function showAction(Request $request, Phrase $phrase = null) {
    ...
    $game = $gameService->getGame($phrase); // Récupération d'une partie
    $form = $this->createForm(GameType::class, $game);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please in English?

Comment: [Explaining why he has to translate] @Alexdu98 Le site est en anglais. Le but du site est de permettre à ta réponse d'aider d'autres personnes, tu peux réussir a traduire tout ca? tu n'es pas obligé d'ajouter autant de contexte. C'est souvent mieux de réduire le probleme a ses aspects techniques.

Comment: Ok sorry, it's my first post. In one line, how to valid a form again manually ? I need to modify the object of my form after handleRequest() if the form was submitted. But if I check if the form isValid() I get always false. I think the validity is check in handleRequest() but I need to check again after modify the object form.

Comment: You would do well to delete this question and start again with a fresh and clear one. In english of course... ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to "revalidate" the form. Change the logic (algorithm).

Try this :

**\GET** (User ask for a game)

Create a new "Game" and pass it to the view.

**\POST** (User submit the answer)

Validate the form ( `handleRequest` ).

- If it's ok ( `$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()` ) create a new "Game" and pass it to the view.
- Else the form (unvalidate with form errors) and the original "Game" are passed to the view

The goal is to generate a new "Game" (entity + form) only on

- \GET request
- \POST if the form is valid

Actually you generate it on each request.

Comment: Thank you for your response.